# MvxException in Release Mode for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i have problem that i can not solve it by myself. I can't run my android api in Release mode, it stops while loading a System.Web.Service.dll library then i got MvxException, after continue i've got the second MvxExcetpion (i guess from debug mode that it is about to close application).

I am using MvvmCross - my application in WindowsPhone7 is working fine, but in Mono for Android i am getting problems.

Here is my output log:

```
- 08-15 17:06:13.242 I/monodroid-gc( 1873): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
- 08-15 17:06:13.292 W/monodroid-gc( 1873): GREF GC Threshold: 1800
- Loaded assembly: SmartWash.UI.dll
- Loaded assembly: SmartWash.Core.dll
- Loaded assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Android.dll
- Loaded assembly: Newtonsoft.Json.MonoDroid.dll
- Loaded assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Android.dll
- Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
- Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
- Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
- Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
- Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll [External]
- Loaded assembly: System.Web.Services.dll [External]
- Unhandled Exception:

- Cirrious.MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: 
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: No Service Factory Constructor included in Assembly!
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxServiceProviderSetup.Initialize (System.Type,Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.IoC.IMvxIoCProvider) <IL 0x0002b, 0x001a8>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxServiceProviderSetup.Initialize (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.IoC.IMvxIoCProvider) <IL 0x00008, 0x0007b>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.IoC.MvxOpenNetCfServiceProviderSetup.Initialize () <IL 0x00007, 0x0008b>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxBaseSetup.InitializeIoC () <IL 0x00000, 0x00043>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxBaseSetup.InitializePrimary () <IL 0x00041, 0x001d7>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Android.Views.MvxBaseSplashScreenActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <IL 0x00036, 0x0018b>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at SmartWash.UI.SplashScreenActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <IL 0x00002, 0x0004f>
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.3-branch/410a5aba/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1490
- 08-15 17:06:31.972 I/MonoDroid( 1873): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.891313b6-5c12-4624-844c-14d43e535064 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00012, 0x00033>
- Unhandled Exception:

- Cirrious.MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException:
```

I have been looking for sollution for days and now i am too tired to get it by myself.. Any suggestions are more than welcome!

UPDATE:
After adding a LinkerIncludePlease.cs class in linking "SDK only" i've got another problem with NullReference where i can not find.

Here is my output:

```
- 08-16 10:08:27.922 I/mono    ( 2334):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Android.ExtensionMethods.MvxAndroidActivityExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate<TViewModel> (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Android.Interfaces.IMvxAndroidView`1<TViewModel>) <IL 0x00043, 0x00243>
- 08-16 10:08:27.922 I/mono    ( 2334):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Android.Views.MvxTabActivityView`1.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <IL 0x00008, 0x00093>
- 08-16 10:08:27.922 I/mono    ( 2334):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Android.Views.MvxBindingTabActivityView`1.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <IL 0x00008, 0x00077>
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
- 08-16 10:08:27.922 I/mono    ( 2334):   at Sm08-16 10:08:27.922 I/mono    ( 2334):   at SmartWash.UI.Views.BaseTabbedView`1.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <IL 0x0000a, 0x00083>
- 08-16 10:08:27.932 I/mono    ( 2334):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00012, 0x000ef>
- 08-16 10:08:27.942 I/mono    ( 2334):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.dc29b95c-fdca-49d9-bdbc-e51d024c54c9 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00012, 0x00033>
08-16 10:08:27.942 I/mono    ( 2334):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.dc29b95c-fdca-49d9-bdbc-e51d024c54c9 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001f, 0xffffffff>
- Unhandled Exception:

- System.NullReferenceException: 

- 08-16 10:08:59.102 I/MonoDroid( 2334): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
- 08-16 10:08:59.102 I/MonoDroid( 2334): at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_intptr__this___intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue[] (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x0005d, 0x0011f>
- 08-16 10:08:59.102 I/MonoDroid( 2334): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x00012, 0x000a7>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that this is release mode only, plus the fact that this is a missing class suggests to me this is probably a monodroid linking problem - the monodroid linker is stripping out too many classes.

The easiest way to solve this is to change the monodroid link settings to "SDK only".

More advanced ways to solve it are to include references to reflection-loaded classes in your main project. Some of the mvx samples include example of this mechanism - look for files called LinkerPleaseInclude.cs (or similar)

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. Well i've add LinkerPleaseInclude.cs class and it works! But only in "SDK only" linking. On "SDK and User Assembly" i've got the same problem. Is there a big diffrence between those options?
Second problem is that, in "SDK only" linking, i've got Login Activity, after log in i should get my MainMenu Activity on with Tabs, but there i've got System.NullReferenceException, and i don't know where it could be null.

Comment: UPDATE: OK, the problem is with AlertBuilder dialogs.. I am creating them by Service in class ReportDisplay to run it from every place in code that i want to and to construct them i need activity and i get it from:

var activity = this.GetService<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;

which gives me null... Any idea?

Comment: Second update: The problem is with not AlertBuilder dialogs, but with warning which forced me to Dispose object after it was created. Now it works fine. Big thanks for you!

Comment: Now i have "Application not installed" with a warning symbol, after instaling on device. Wrong linking or something?

Comment: Separate question - and sounds like a general android or mono droid issue, rather than an mvvmcross thing?