# issues with MvvmCross and linking on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an Android app using several MvxGridView with ItemsSource bound

```
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Groups;ItemClick ShowGroupCommand"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Products;ItemClick ShowProductCommand"
```

When running app in Release mode, link behavior='Don't link', app size is 20MB!, everything works as expected.

Switching link behavior to 'Link SDK assemblies only', app size is 7MB, but when running I get unexpected behavior. 
  Here is some of the app output which mention issues with the MvxGridView's ItemsSource binding:

http://pastebin.com/smDf1Ekc

I am aware of the linking options in Xamarin ([here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking)).

But I don't know what I should do in order to make it work.

I am working on a small pilot app, I need to send it to client to check it out. It won't look good sending 20MB when the full Android app I want to rewrite with Xamarin and MVVMcross is under 1MB.
  I already spent a lot of time on this issue with no luck, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to work around this including:

- using a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file - a starter one is included by default in the nuget packages (see [LinkerPleaseInclude.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/nuspec/DroidContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp))
- using a Linker xml file - like the one ReactiveUI uses for MonoTouch - see [Linker.xml](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui5-master/ReactiveUI.Platforms/Cocoa/Buildsupport/Linker.xml)

---

There are also plenty of questions and answers on here about this already:

- [Android App is too large and Linking disables functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613694/android-app-is-too-large-and-linking-disables-functionality/15614346#15614346)
- [Trouble with xamarin.ios/monotouch , mvvmcross and linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441506/trouble-with-xamarin-ios-monotouch-mvvmcross-and-linking/16441943#16441943)
- [Problems with mvvmcross Binding on IOS (Works on Simulator, but some properties doesn't work on the Device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275499/problems-with-mvvmcross-binding-on-ios-works-on-simulator-but-some-properties)
- [MvvmCross Monotouch - Fail to bind Properties on a real iPad, but it works on the Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349864/mvvmcross-monotouch-fail-to-bind-properties-on-a-real-ipad-but-it-works-on-th)
- [MvxException in Release Mode for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973993/mvxexception-in-release-mode-for-android)

Comment: Thank you Stuart. I was already using LinkerPleaseInclude.cs but I had no clue what exactly to reference there to make it work. The error is a bit criptic. Adding reference to INotifyCollectionChanged made it work. Is there an easier option to make 'SDK Libraries only' linking work but without the adding code to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs? To me it looks a bit problematic because it makes the app hard to test. Some parts of the app (screens) can use some specific functionality which break the app only in that particular place / usage. I can open a different question if necessary.

Comment: "The error is a bit criptic." - if you can improve it, please do. " Is there an easier option" - please see my existing answer - others may know other answers but I do generally try to give the best answer I can.

Comment: thank you again Stuart. It's cryptic for people less experienced with MVVMCross like me.

Comment: Seriously - the stack trace and the source code is there - if you can think of a way of making it less cryptic then I'm very open to ideas :)

Comment: I don't see a way to address that problem directly. It's a linker issue and the errors can't be pretty. I like Xamarin, C# and MVVCross but I don't have a deep understanding of how the linking works to suggest a solution.  For example, I would have expected more issues with the binding to the ViewModels properties. It's code which is used by reflection at run-time, I'm not sure how that works OK but not other things like the issue I had.